# Why using important in css is Bad practice?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

HTML:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
  <ul id="menu-primary" class="nav navbar-nav menustyle">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menustyle a:before{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: "";
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 0%;
}
.nav > li > a:hover .menustyle a:before{
  width: 100%!important;
}
```

This is not working when I use Bootstrap but works without bootstrap.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
I have modified you code. If you want hover like this.

    <style type="text/css">           
        .menustyle a{
            position: relative;
        }
        .menustyle a:before{
                position: absolute;
                top: -5px;
                left: 0;
                content: "";
                height: 2px;
                background-color: #ff0000;
                width: 0%;
            }
        .menustyle > li > a:hover:before{
            width: 100% !important;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <ul id="menu-primary" class="nav navbar-nav menustyle">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: But width:100% is not suitable for all <li>..How to give equivalent width?

Comment: You can use margin: 0 15px; display:inline-block; to <li> in css. Or share with me link so i will explain you better.

Comment: I used this without bootstrap width is equal for all li but when i use bootstrap the width varies

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `.nav > li > a:hover:before` instead of `.nav > li > a:hover .menustyle a:before`...

`.nav > li > a:hover .menustyle a:before`....means it will target all the `.menustyle a` elements inside a `<a>` tag.

```
.nav > li > a:hover:before {
  width: 100%;
}
```

**[Fiddle Link](https://fiddle.jshell.net/bhuwanb9/bg2kqw12/)**

Comment: Thanks, @Bhuwan It working on your suggestion.  width: 100% give different width for different <li> <a>. How to give equivalent width. Can you pls help me

Comment: @RameshKR you want to give fixed width to all <a>..?

Comment: @RameshKR - That is a completely different question and should be asked separately. Good answer and nice explanation, Bhuwan, +1.

Comment: Because I can't ask a question right now StackOverflow restricted me.